# How to make an Android application use specific version of another application

Tags: android, version

I have to develop an Android application which should access a specific version of another application installed on the same machine. Is there a way we can handle this check programmatically? I am an Android newbie. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance,
Navin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way we can handle this check programmatically?

Use `PackageManager` and `getPackageInfo()` to get a `PackageInfo` object for the specific application, identified by its package (e.g., `com.commonsware.mygreatapp`). The `versionCode` and `versionName` fields on the `PackageInfo` will have the information you seek.

Comment: NOw that I have the check done, I need someone to help me comeup with code that I can use to invoke that particular version of the another applicaiton. To give more details: My application contains a list of Pdf documents and when the user clicks on any document, adobe reader should automatically open up with the selected document. It should not show a list of all pdf viewers installed on the machine and let user select the choice. Is there a way we can implement this? You help will be very much appreciated. Thanks